# Have any example of how to configure Express 4 and Handlebars 3?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

Does anyone have an example of how to use Express 4 and Handlebars 3 in a Node.Js app?. Specially, the initial configuration part when you whoud define the view engine. All examples I see use the old syntax

```
var handlebars=require("express3-handlebars");
```

but that doesn't work with version 3 of Handlebars. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using [`hbs`](https://github.com/donpark/hbs) instead?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like express3-handlebars migrated to [express-handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars).

Here is an example working with [express-handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars):

The server file, `app.js`:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');

app.engine('handlebars', expressHbs({defaultLayout: 'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

app.listen(4040, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at http://localhost:4040');
});
```

Here is the layout, `views/layouts/layout.handlebars`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Example Handlebars with Express</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    {{{body}}}
  </body>

</html>
```

My index file, `views/index.handlebars`:

```
<h1> Hello World </h1>
```

If you want to see a more detailed example, see the `examples` directory in [their github repository](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars/tree/master/examples).